# SharePoint 2010 DateTime Culture Format Error

Tags: sharepoint, datetime, sharepoint-2010, cultureinfo

I'm trying to pass a Datetime to SharePoint list. For german datetime format it works, but it needs to be variable so i tried this:

```
itemsList[i]["FTPDate"] = DateTime.ParseExact(entity.FTPDate.ToString("dd MMM yyyy"), "dd MMM yyyy", Culture);
```

but I still get an invalid data exception.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharepoint dates are saved according to ISO8061, there is a helper method on the SPUtility class that can convert your datetime to the correct string.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.createiso8601datetimefromsystemdatetime.aspx